# How do I create a main import file in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am looking to create a main import file using `ES6` syntax. I have a components directory with an *index.js* file.

I would like to `export` the imports if that makes sense. Essentially, I would like to import then export the individual component files into the index file so I can de-structure my `imports` from any other files like so:

```
import {Comp1, Comp2} from "./components"
```

How do I do this with `ES6` syntax?

Comment: Wait, I think I misunderstood your question. You're asking about a way to gather exports from all other modules in the same directory as `index.js` and make `index.js` export all of those exports?

Comment: @JMM Yes. To follow my example, I just used `export Comp1 from "./comp1"` inside of index.js. This worked just fine. Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought maybe you were asking about a way to *dynamically* process other modules in the same directory to collect their exports, which would require some kind of additional build step.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do:

```js
export * from "./components"
// or
export {Comp1, Comp2} from "./components"
```

How exactly to reference `components/index.js` depends on your module loader or the module format you're compiling to. I'm not sure what happens if you do `export * from` multiple modules that have overlapping named exports (will have to check).

Comment: This works great! I didn't realize it was that simple. Thank you.

Comment: Oh ok, great. After I posted I thought maybe I misunderstood your question. You're welcome.