# Import index file for directory not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module, ecmascript-6

The following contents of the application.js file report that "home" being imported is undefined.

```
import {home} from "./routes/index"
console.log(JSON.stringify(home, null, 4))
```

The content of index.js are as follows:

```
export * from "./home.js"
```

The content of home.js are as follows:

```
export const type = "GET"

export const route = "/"

export const middleware = [];

export const action = function(req, res) {
    res.send("Testing custom routes");
}
```

A picture of the directory structure is as follows:

[image: directory]

Comment: Your exports are not prefixed by `home`. Try `import { middleware } from "./routes"` (no need for index). Same works for `type`, `route`, and `action` in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not exporting anything named `home`. If you want to attach everything *you are* exporting to a variable named `home` then use `as`.

```
import * as home from './routes/index';
```

See [here for more information on import/export](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html).

Comment: I have tried this and have gotten the error: `SyntaxError: src/routes/index.js: Unexpected token (1:9)
export * as home from "./home.js"`

Comment: @Connorelsea `import`, not `export`. This should replace `import {home} from "./routes/index"`

Comment: But the goal is to create an index file for the directory that allows all the files in the directory to be accessed. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914796/how-do-i-create-a-main-import-file-in-es6

Comment: @Connorelsea I know. Your exports are fine. Your import is messed up.

Comment: In the future I want to import multiple items that are being exported. So with the as, seems like I could only import one thing.

Comment: I get what you're saying. It worked. Trying to stringily it was giving weird results but it works normally I think now.

Comment: Then put this in your index.js. `import * as home from './home.js';` Then later, `export { home: home }`. Then you can add an entry for anything else. To import it, use your original import statement in your question. It will work because you actually named the export.

Answer (score 1):

You could structure your code like so to achieve the effect you want:

**application.js**

```
import { home } from './routes';
```

**home.js**

```
const type = "GET"
const route = "/"
const middleware = [];
const action = function(req, res) {
    res.send("Testing custom routes");
}

export default {
    type,
    route,
    middleware,
    action
};
```

**index.js**

```
import * as home from './home.js';
export default {
    home
};
```